# Why might TypeScript not be enforcing a type declared for a class property?

Tags: class, typescript, types

This is on a large code base, so I'm just looking for general pointers.

In one file, a function takes a parameter `a:MyClass`.

At runtime, `typeof a.b` yields `string`.

In VSCode I hit F12 on the `b` of `a.b` and am brought (correctly, judging by the import statement) to another file:

```
export class MyClass {
  ...
  b: string[]; // brought to this line
}
```

How is it possible within a TypeScript environment for `a.b` to be a `string` instead of a `string[]` like the class declaration says?  And what should I look for that might cause this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type declarations in TypeScript are only suggestive. Because TypeScript is transpiled into plain JavaScript it can not make any guarantees about the actual content of a variable.

Even in TypeScript itself is fairly easy to put an object of a different type in a variable:

```
let myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.b = "I'm a string placed into a string array" as any;
```

Notice the `as any` at the end of the last line, this removes type information from an expression and allows it to be placed into a variable or argument of any type.

Comment: Thanks, I started to trace it back and saw that `a` comes in as the return value of a function declared to return `any`.  Hmm...we seem to have defeated the suggestive powers of the language here.  :)

Comment: Yes. `any` is opting out of static typing.